# The code does not work until after restarting the server

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a problem with the form file
I wrote a code, but it does not work properly until after restarting the server

```
def PAYMENT_CHOICES():
    check_pay=payment.objects.first()
    if check_pay.payment == '1':
        return (('COD', 'Cash on delivery'),)
    elif check_pay.payment == '2':
        return (('CARD', 'Credit card'),)
    elif check_pay.payment == '3':
        return (('COD', 'Cash on delivery'),
                ('CARD', 'Credit card'))
class paymentForm(forms.Form):
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES())
```

and in template

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

            {% for value, name in form.fields.payment_option.choices %}

       <div class="agree-label">
         <input type="radio" name="payment_option" id="{{ name }}" value="{{ value }}" required>
            <label for="{{ name }}">
               {{ name }} 
            </label>
      </div>
          {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` file, also explain well. I don't understand what you're trying to do. And I don't think that's a `forms.py` file

Comment: I am trying to control the payment method through the dashboard.  The forms file fetches the data through the database and displays it to the customer.  The problem is that when I choose number 2 from the dashboard, for example, it doesn't change until after restarting the server.  The code works fine, but I have to a restart when I try to change the option from dashboard every time ?? !!